# after git push not changing the permission of a directory?

Tags: git, laravel-5, file-permissions

I am also use the .gitignore to exclude it from the project but it will change the permission of a directory as /Public/example/

So how to ignore a file or directory from a git while pushing not changing the permission of a specific folder.

Thanks in advance!!
In laravel 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will tell git to ignore permissions:

```
git config core.filemode false
```

http://www.ivankristianto.com/git-ignore-file-permission/

Comment: Is there any other way to do this??

Comment: this is staned way. u can do with chmod change but it will effect for firewall